# How many mapper is used in hive to process Table of 1GB

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, mapper

This has been asked to me ..

If there are 10 nodes and Table of 1GB is need to process in hive. So how many mapper is used ?

Comment: it's one of the questions I ask in interviews... it depends on how the table is configured, its file format, and how HDFS is configured.

Comment: Roberto Thanks for reply , Can you please be more brief on this ?  Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1):

**How to determine the number of mappers?**

It’s relatively easy to determine but harder to control the number of mappers as compared to the number of reducers.
Number of mappers can be determined as follows:
First determine that the input files are splittable or not. GZipped files and some other compressed files are inherently not splittable by the Hadoop. Normal text files, JSON docs etc. are splittable.

**If the files are splittable:**

1. Calculate the total size of input files.
2. The number of mappers = total size calculated above / input split size defined in Hadoop configuration.
   For example, if the total size of input is 1GB and input split size is set to 128 MB then:
   number of mappers = 1 x 1024 / 128 = 8 mappers.

**If the files are not splittable:**

1. In this case the number of mappers is equal to the number of input files.

Also, The fileformat also plays a role too.

Comment: Hi Nidhin, Since, it's Hive (HDFS) table. I think , splitting is already been done. While working with hadoop it's good to say 'number of split = number of mapper '.  But it is works in Hive ?